# php mcrypt_decrypt() issue

Tags: php, mcrypt

I'm passing information from one page another with following php code..

**Index.php page:**

```
<?php
include("secure/content/database/db.php");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM press");
while($re =  mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{   


$id= (int) $re['id'];                   

$key = "bladeyeshibbir?1%59";

$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM)       

$encrypted_data=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $id, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

$id = urlencode(base64_encode($encrypted_data));

$page = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($re['pagename']));
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($re['content']));
echo "<li><a href='press.php?id=$id&request=$md'>$page</a></li>";
            }

            ?>
```

**Press.php page**

```
<?php
include("secure/content/database/db.php");
include("header.php");

$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$key = "bladeyeshibbir?1%59#";

$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM)       

$decrypted_data=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $id, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 
$url_id = base64_decode(urldecode($decrypted_data));

$request = $_REQUEST['request'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM press WHERE id='$url_id'  ");
$re = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$pagename = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($re['pagename']));
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($re['content']));  

echo "<title>$pagename</title>";

echo $content;

include("fotter.php");

?>
```

**BUT** I'm getting this error:

> Warning: mcrypt_decrypt() [function.mcrypt-decrypt]: Attempt to use an
>   empty IV, which is NOT recommend in C:\xampp\htdocs\audock\press.php
>   on line 10.

Actually, what I want is that the user can't see the actual value of the query string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=256425). You shouldn't use `mcrypt_ecb` with `mcrypt_decrypt`, you should use `mcrypt_encrypt`. Then, when encrypting with `mcrypt_encrypt` you'll need to create an Initialization Vector with `mcrypt_create_iv` ([docs here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php)) which you should afterwards use for decrypting as well.

Comment: Why are you using your custom IV instead of using the `mcryp_create_iv ` function? Also, try passing the same IV to the encrypt and the decrypt functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing"? Is it giving you the same error, is it not doing what you expect? I see in your code you're calling descrypt more than once, so try commenting out the calls you're not using. Also  I'm not sure how `mycript_create_iv` works, but you're calling it twice (once in every file) and I'm not sure if they produce the same output. You should check that too.

Answer (score 0):

Example with a zero byte iv

```
$encrypted_data=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $id, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
```